# In Python, does DummyThread uniquely identify the current thread?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, google-app-engine, thread-safety

**Edit:** by multithreading, I mean I've set `threadsafe: true` in my app.yaml, not that I am trying to create my own threads.

I've been trying to use multithreading in my GoogleAppEngine Python application.

**Some background:**

I use Django for templating, using a custom template loader. The first time a template is passed to a template loader in Django, the full path to the template is given. However, for other template files that a template references (via `include` and `extend`), only the filename is passed in, and it's up to the loader to find the full path to the file. In order to do this, the full path from the first template is stored on the loader and it then uses that path to try and find any further files that get passed in.

This is fine in a single-threaded enviroment, but in a multithreaded one this means that if rendering a child template for one request is taking a long time due to datastore requests or whatever, another request can try to use the loader to find a file and overwrite the stored path. When the first request comes back and tries to load more child templates, the loader looks in the wrong place and raises a TemplateDoesNotExist error.

**My proposed solution:**

If I had some way to get either the current thread, or the current request, then I could create a mapping of threads/requests to search paths in the loader.

`threading.current_thread()` is supposed to return the current thread (assuming that the thread was created with `threading`)

But on AppEngine, when I call threading.current_thread() , it returns a DummyThread like `<_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 4424339456)>`.

I'm unclear on whether I can safely use this DummyThread to identify the current thread, or whether I need to find some other way to get the current thread?

Comment: yes, but it probably won't help you, see: [Why does Google App Engine support a single thread of execution only?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3800435/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- If DummyThread can uniquely identify the current thread, even though it was not spawned by `threading`, then that's all I need. I'm not trying to spawn my own threads.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian OTOH, it seems possible that using DummyThread like this may lead to a memory leak, as they never get deleted, even when the alien thread they refer to ends.

Comment: yes, [DummyThread is not garbage collected](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/threading.py#l853).